# How to move element programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an element I have coded but I can't seem to get the code right so I can set the position of this on the screen. Here is my code:

```
- (void)setShowsRadar:(BOOL)showsRadar{
    _showsRadar = showsRadar;
    [_agController setShowsRadar:_showsRadar];
}
```

I want to position it like this:

```
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 22, 60, 30)];
```

Comment: something.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);

Comment: @Omar, please show the code inside `setShowsRadar:`

Answer (score 0):

yourView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);

Comment: well if you will specify what do you want to move, and subclass of what is it then I can.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that but the code I have provided above is what I have

Comment: What is that element you want to move?

Comment: It's defined in .h file like this @property (assign, nonatomic, setter = setShowsRadar:)                      BOOL showsRadar; - i believe it is a subview

Comment: it is BOOL -> boolean the variable that holds (yes/no) equalient to true/false